# Convert to valid json string or object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, escaping

This document in my MongoDB collection has been driving me crazy cos of one field "attributes". I understand what 'escaping' characters mean but I want the attributes field to be properly readable (I mean parse-able) by javascript or php. How do I make the attribute field either to valid JSON string or object. I have tried most of the solutions on SO to replace the /" with "....or even simply removing the / may help I guess. But I am unable to get rid of the /" or replace it with something else, no matter what. The data as stored in my MongoDB is shown below. The data is posted to MongoDB by means of an URL that looks like this

```
{
    "attributes": "{\"alarm\":true,\"ignition\":false,\"status\":68,\"power\":6,\"gsm\":4,\"index\":271,\"ip\":\"192.168.255.11\"}",
    "latitude": 1.43365,
    "longitude": 103.7859383
}
```

The data originally was posted to MongoDB by a HTTP POST and the URL when decoded looks like this

```
http://example.com/api/mongodb-insert/data?attributes={"alarm":true,"ignition":false,"status":68,"power":6,"gsm":4,"index":271,"ip":"192.168.255.11"}
```

I have almost tried every solution on SO but strangely the \" stays. I am still scratching my head over this :-) .... should've been easy

Comment: If I remember correctly this is part of the JSON Standart and **must** be escaped, a JSON.parse should have no problem with this..

Comment: Fantastic thanks Nick!!! Yes, that was it. JSON.parse was able to understand that correctly